# Where are my terraria character plr. files? Im playing steam version

Tags: terraria

I need to find my pLr. files for my terraria character but i have steam version so can't find them! Where are they can anyone help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no non-steam version.

Comment: @Arperum GOG has a DRM free version https://www.gog.com/game/terraria

Comment: TIL. Didn't know that. I would assume that the saves are in the same place for everyone

Comment: Where have you looked?